# where is my SQLite database on real device?

Tags: android

on the emulator, my SQLite database lives in /data/data/pkg.path.whatever

however, once I put the app on the device, I can't find it to run SQLiteSpy or some other such tool.
Any idea where it lives on a real device?  I'm testing on a Samsung Galaxy S and have looked all
through the folders to no avail.  On the device there IS a /data folder and the permissions are
open (drwxrwx--x) but clicking on it in Eclipse does nothing.  Is there a driver I'm missing to be able to see that in Windows or in Eclipse?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is stored under the same conditions that are in the emulator, the difference is that you can't access it unless your phone is rooted!

Comment: Ugh!  I hate the thought of rooting my phone - it ain't a test device, but my real life communication device. The thought of jacking it up and dealing with Korean service (I live in Korea) doesn't thrill me.  Thanks for the info, tho.

Answer (score 0):

Its in `/data/data/packagename/databases/`